# How should I set up FQDN identity for kubernetes pods in local cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, fqdn

This question is relevant to local cluster (kubernetes 1.10+ version, Linux). After creating a StatefulSet to manage several pods, I met a use case that requires setting up FQDN identity for the pods.

For instance, I wish to have the first pod with FQDN identity of `<some-statefulset>-0.<some-subdomain>.default.svc.cluster.local`. Desired behavior can be achieved by adding `<IP-address> <some-statefulset>-0.<some-subdomain>.default.svc.cluster.local` into `/etc/hosts` file, but I want to have the FQDN to be identified automatically in the local cluster without changing the `/etc/hosts` file.

Not sure whether I need to enable some settings when starting the local cluster.

Comment: Are you talking about being able to access them internally to the cluster, or from outside? When you use a ``StatefulSet`` you usually want to have a headless service with it. This will provide you DNS names for accessing them within the cluster. See https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#headless-services and https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/#srv-records

Comment: I updated the question with a FQDN example. I did set up a headless service that has the same name as the pod's subdomain, but I still not able to check the hostname using nslookup.

Comment: If you have a DNS deployed for your Kubernetes cluster, you should already be able to use ``my-pod-0.my-svc.my-namespace.svc.cluster.local``. Does that at least work? Can you show a concrete example of the FQDN you have already tried? If have internal DNS working it should work without mucking around with ``/etc/hosts``.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. The FQDN I tried (`some-statefulset-0.some-service.default.svc.cluster.local`) has exactly the same format as the one you suggested, but I am not able to use it.

My guess is `kube-dns` add-on didn't set up correctly on local cluster. I went over this [tutorial](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-debugging-resolution/), but found out that some necessary steps failed. I will continue working at the direction suggested by the tutorial, and post my findings if I am able to answer my own question.

Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: Was your use case related to bypassing proxy for internal requests ?

Answer (score 1):

By default the cluster.local is the internal domain. To reach service from pods within the cluster,

> svc_name.namespace_name.cluster.local

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all. The question is about to get the pod with the domain configured automatically so that the `hostname --domain` command from the pod outputs something.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `hostname` and `subdomain` in the pod spec.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/#pod-s-hostname-and-subdomain-fields